# RAID FS detection at boot time

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, gentoo

An excerpt from **dmesg**:

```
md: Autodetecting RAID arrays.
md: Scanned 2 and added 2 devices.
md: autorun ...
md: considering sdb1 ...
md:  adding sdb1 ...
md:  adding sda1 ...
md: created md1
md: bind<sda1>
md: bind<sdb1>
md: running: <sdb1><sda1>
raid1: raid set md1 active with 2 out of 2 mirrors
md1: detected capacity change from 0 to 1500299198464
md: ... autorun DONE.
 md1: unknown partition table
EXT3-fs (md1): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (240)
EXT2-fs (md1): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (240)
EXT4-fs (md1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
```

Is it OK that kernel tries to mount an ext4 raid as ext3, ext2 first?
Is there a way to tell it to skip those two steps?

```
# mdadm --detail --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=0.90 UUID=56851215:5dca6eee:776c2c25:004bd7b2

# grep dev/md /etc/fstab
/dev/md1                /               ext4            noatime         0 1
```

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly normal that the kernel probes the filesystem for the correct driver to use to mount the file system.  I've had a Linux box before probe for XFS, JFS, and a few others before it got to loading the ext4 driver up.  The only harm was the error messages in dmesg.

Answer (score 0):

it has nothing to do with RAID.  the only interesting snippet is the one of `/etc/fstab`; but for `/` you have to check the `/etc/fstab` included in the `initramfs` file.

Comment: Thanks.  
Initramfs is a generic one produced by genkernel:    
`/dev/ram0     /           ext2    defaults      0 0`